# Separating Strings and other values with comma as a delimiter

Tags: python, split

I'm working with a project, where there will be variable holding any data types just separated with a comma.

I need to separate all these things and I also need to define which type it is.

For e.g:

```
data='"Hello, Hey",123,10.04'
```

I used split() function to separate, but it separates the comma even within  "Hello,Hey", outputing:

```
['"Hello','Hey"','123','10'.'04']
```

I don't need it like this, all i need is to separate the values by commas but not the ones inside other quotes. The output should be like this:

```
['"Hello, Hey"','123','10.04']
```

I killed my brain, but it is still a problem for me. Because I'm a beginner.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you working with csv files?

Comment: Consider storing your data in a list, not a string.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Is your code _required_ to accept data as CSV strings? If not, then change your data model. If you have to process CSV data like this, research regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling to understand your question - it seems you have a string with data inside the string, separated by commas:

```
data='"Hello, Hey",123,10.04'
```

You can use the [`shlex` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) to split it respecting the quotes

```
>>> import shlex
>>> s = shlex.shlex(data)
>>> s.whitespace = ','
>>> s.wordchars += '.'
>>> print(list(s))
['"Hello, Hey"', '123', '10.04']
```

Comment: Nice one! Didn't think of using shlex.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `re` module like so:

```
[m.group(1) or m.group(2) for m in re.finditer(r'"([^"]*)",?|([^,]*),?', '"Hello, Hey",123,10.04')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall` with regex pattern `"[^"]+"|[^,]+`:

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'"[^"]+"|[^,]+', '"Hello, Hey",123,10.04'))
```

This outputs:

```
['"Hello, Hey"', '123', '10.04']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the shlex module

```
import shlex 

data = '"Hello, Hey",123,10.04'
data = shlex.split(data)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
["Hello, Hey", "123" , "10.04"]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `re.split` to split on a combination of either a double quote before a comma or a comma followed by a digit

```
import re

data='"Hello, Hey",123,10.04'
re.split(r'(?<="),|,(?=\d)', data)
['"Hello, Hey"', '123', '10.04']
```