# How to split a comma-separated line if the chunk contains a comma in Python?

Tags: python, split

I'm trying to split current line into 3 chunks.
Title column contains comma which is delimiter

```
1,"Rink, The (1916)",Comedy
```

Current code is not working

```
id, title, genres = line.split(',')
```

Expected result

```
id = 1
title = 'Rink, The (1916)'
genres = 'Comedy'
```

Any thoughts how to split it properly?

Comment: Did you check [Split by comma and how to exclude comma from quotes in split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067373/split-by-comma-and-how-to-exclude-comma-from-quotes-in-split)

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51106304/separating-strings-and-other-values-with-comma-as-a-delimiter

Comment: You're right. It contains a similar solution provided by Tim below. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you should use a proper CSV parser and specify that double quote is an escape character.  If you *must* proceed with the current string as the starting point, here is a regex trick which should work:

```py
inp = '1,"Rink, The (1916)",Comedy'
parts = re.findall(r'".*?"|[^,]+', inp)
print(parts)  # ['1', '"Rink, The (1916)"', 'Comedy']
```

The regex pattern works by first trying to find a term `"..."` in double quotes.  That failing, it falls back to finding a CSV term which is defined as a sequence of non comma characters (leading up to the next comma or end of the line).

Answer (score 0):

Use the csv package from the standard library:

```
>>> import csv, io
>>> s = """1,"Rink, The (1916)",Comedy"""
>>> # Load the string into a buffer so that csv reader will accept it.
>>> reader = csv.reader(io.StringIO(s))
>>> next(reader)
['1', 'Rink, The (1916)', 'Comedy']
```

Comment: Does anyone know what performs better whether regex or csv parser?

Answer (score 0):

lets talk about why your code does not work

```
id, title, genres = line.split(',')
```

here line.split(',') return 4 values(since you have 3 commas) on the other hand you are expecting 3 values hence you get.

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

My advice to you will be to not use commas but use other characters

```
"1#\"Rink, The (1916)\"#Comedy"
```

and then

```
id, title, genres = line.split('#')
```

Comment: Good suggestion. But I can't change the input data.

Answer (score -1):

Well you can do it by making it a tuple

```
line = (1,"Rink, The (1916)",Comedy)
id, title, genres = line
```